# SPARQL query filtered by minus 100 km from a specific geo:lat and geo:long

Tags: sparql

I have a database that contains msgs. each msg has geo:long geo:lat stored in the database. 
I want to get the msgs that were sent from less than 100 kilometres from different specified geo:long geo:lat  which is (50.25 -90.25)

```
PREFIX off: <http://www.semanticweb.org/balo/ontologies/2020/1/MSGING#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX spatial: <http://jena.apache.org/spatial#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?msg
WHERE {
?msg rdf:type off:Msg.
?msg geo:long ?long.
?msg geo:lat ?lat
}
```

The code above is missing the filter, but I have put it for reflection. 
What should I write as a filter?

Note: I am using StarDog to do the queries.

I came up with this solution and its returning resluts, is it acceptable?

```
PREFIX off: <http://www.semanticweb.org/balo/ontologies/2020/1/MSGING#>
PREFIX geosf: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT ?msg ?airline
WHERE {
?msg rdf:type off:msg;
off:has_airline ?airline;
geosf:nearby("50.25" "-90.25" 100 <http://qudt.org/vocab/unit#Kilometer> ) .
}
```

Comment: there is no answer to this without knowing your triple store. Some of them do have geospatial extension like GeoSPARQL - you could use this. If not., you'd have to do the math by yourself which is clearly less efficient than using a spatial index.

Comment: i apologise i didn't understand well, do you refer to the data file (the database itself) or the enterprise i am using, the enterprise i am using is StarDog would you like me to export the database to a file and link it? or kindly what are you referring to?

Comment: it's not called "enterprise" - call it RDF database, just triple store, SPARQL engine or whatever - and yes, I was referring to SPARQL. I mean, obviously, computing the distance on the earth sphere is something you could compute by yourself, but it sounds like you're not familiar with those measures. That's why I was saying that the triple store - in your case Stardog - might support geospatial queries - and Stardog does in fact. Read the docs please, everything is online: https://www.stardog.com/docs/#_geospatial_query - and read it carefully please, you also have to enable the geo support

Comment: Thanks, I think i came up with a solution, I appended it to the post. kindly would you please check it out if it's correct.

Comment: if it works for you, it's correct I'd say. I mean, you simply check the results. For me the query looks ok

Answer (score 0):

```
PREFIX off: <http://www.semanticweb.org/balo/ontologies/2020/1/MSGING#>
PREFIX geosf: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT ?msg ?airline
WHERE {
?msg rdf:type off:msg;
off:has_airline ?airline;
geosf:nearby("50.25" "-90.25" 100 <http://qudt.org/vocab/unit#Kilometer> ) .
}
```